# How to add a legend to a pyplot whose items depend on integer variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, k-means, scatter-plot

I am implementing a K-Means clustering algorithm. I want to show the clustered data-sets (each a different color) in one scatter-plot. I do this as follows:

```
for i in range(k):
    plt.scatter(np.array(clustersets[i])[:, 0], np.array(clustersets[i])[:, 1], c=c_map(i))
```

, where k is the number of centers (-> number of cluster-sets) in my scatter-plot. 
I now want to add a legend that contains 1 item for each of these data-sets. This hence depends on the pre-defined number `k`.

How can I add a legend such that it will cover all the different items in my scatter-plot, disregarding what `k` is?

Comment: The size of the legend thus depends on `k`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a legends going from `0` to `k`. You can use the `label` option with a fiel specifier `%d` to specify the dataset.

```
for i in range(k):
    plt.scatter(np.array(clustersets[i])[:, 0], 
                np.array(clustersets[i])[:, 1], c=c_map(i), label='Dataset %d' %i)
plt.legend()
```

Comment: You understood me correctly. I have a function `kmeans(X, k)` (`X` for data, `k` for number of cluster centers). Inside of this function, I define the plot. If I run my function for e.g. `k=3`, I want to see a scatter-plot with a legend consisting of 3 items.

Comment: @RutgerMauritz: Did you try my solution? For k=3, it should give you 3 legends

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `c=KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(X).labels_astype(float)` ?